# How to know whether the bandpass filter is stable

Tags: amplifier, analog, filter, stability

I am designing a bandpass filter using MFB. However, I do not know whether my filter is stable or not. Can anyone give me some criteria or methods to evaluate the stability of the filter design?(still using bode plot and applying the Barkhausen stability criterion?)

Here is the schematic in Multisim and the AC analysis plot:
[image]

[image]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

This is a second order biquadratic band pass filter (see [HERE](http://opencourseware.kfupm.edu.sa/colleges/ces/ee/ee303/files%5C3-Lesson_Notes_Lecture_19.pdf)).  The transfer function is
$$ \frac{-sC_2R_2R_3}{s^2C_1C_2R_1R_2R_3 + s\left ( C_1+C_2 \right )R_1R_2 + \left ( R_1+R_2 \right )} $$

If the poles (those values of s for which the denominator equals zero) all lie in the left half of the s-plane (x-axis, reals; y-axis, imaginary), then the system is stable

```
>> denom=[C1*C2*R1*R2*R3 (C1+C2)*R1*R2 R1+R2]

denom =

   1.0e+04 *

    0.0000    0.0000    1.2474

>> roots(denom)

ans =

   1.0e+04 *

  -0.0535 + 1.2129i
  -0.0535 - 1.2129i
```

The real part of your roots are negative, thus all the poles lie in the left half of the s-plane, and your system is stable.

The Bode plot I get is:
[image]

Your routine plotted the 270 degree phase lead as a 90 degree lag, but otherwise the bodes are close to matching.  Your system is stable.

Comment: However, one should add that this stability check is valid under assumption of an IDEAL opamp only. It is well-known that the TOPOLOGY itself is always stable. Instability can be caused by real opamp properties (introducing additional poles) only.

Comment: I'd be very suspect if an op amp were messing around with poles at around 2kHz.

Comment: @ScottSeidman you have too many ")" in your formula but nice answer (am I allowed to say that LOL) +1

Comment: @LvW Yeah the plot is strange. The picture comes from the Multisim. I think my setting is ok. Then what would be the problem you think?

Comment: I have improved the resolution(10000 points/decade), the rising edge still exists.What would be the problem

Comment: @ScottSeidman Could I ask how to read the stability from the Bode Plot? I only knew to check the phase margin when loop gain = 1. However I do not see that the margin could be read on Bode plot when loop gain =1.

Comment: @billyzhao: "The rising edge..." - I suppose you are referring to the rising part of the phase plot, right? I don`t understand - the phase plot must look as shown above by Scott Seidman. For example: At the center frequency (app. 2kHz) the phase must cross the -180deg line. Can you update your figures (better resolution) ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few tools that can analyse this for you. Here are the results from Mr. Okawa: -

[image]

[Here](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPttool.php) is the site and I've taken the liberty of summarizing the results. Note those numbers with the red boxes - in particular the phase margin quoted is |82.6 degrees| when the gain becomes 0dB. This looks pretty acceptable to me.

Comment: May I point to the fact that the phase margin must be determined using the LOOP GAIN function only. Therefore, the margin will me much smaller than 82.6 deg.

Comment: @LvW We've been here before and you are right. I didn't question the website's authenticity on this but there is a comment box that I may leave something on regarding this subject.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you.But in that website, a comment said that the oscillation frequency is about 1930Hz. What would be the problem?

Comment: @billyzhao It's called the oscillation frequency but it doesn't mean it will oscillate - this will be the frequency where the phase shift from input to output is precisely 180 degrees - so if you happened to use this bpf in a circuit around an inverting amplifier, this is the frequency the combined circuit would oscillate at.

Comment: @billyzhao: Supplementing the comment from Andy aka the given "oscillation frequency" is also the frequency you can observe as a step response (see the last figure displayed on the web page). Note that each high-Q circuit (in your example: Q=11) will exhibit a step response with ringing at a frequency which equals the ple frequency.

Comment: @Andy aka: Only now I had the chance to check the website you have mentioned - and, indeed, I am surprised that they didn´t apply the correct method to find the stability margin. Thank you for pointing to this.

Comment: @Andy aka: I just had a more detailed look into the tools presented on that website: All calcualtions (amplifiers, filters,..) are based on the assumption of IDEAL amplifiers (infinite gain). Hence, all values for the phase margin are - sorry - "garbage", because the loop gain NEVER reaches zero dB. (Example: Phase margin for a simple opamp based gain stage: 180 deg.). Nevertheless, for all other parameters the website can be a helpful tool.

Comment: Thank you LvW and Andy aka! I think the website can be used to find the approximate value of the components.

Comment: @LvW I sent them an email last night pointing out that their phase margin didn't take into account that the op-amp would likely be producing a phase shift around 90 degrees above 10Hz thus turning a so-called phase margin of -82 degrees into something more like 8 degrees! I use the site a lot for theoretical stuff and apart from this "glitch" I rate it highly.

Comment: @billyzhao I definitely can but, as per the discussion with LvW it does assume perfect op-amps - just bear this in mind. I use this site a lot because it is really neat - a stackfull of filter designs in one place!

Comment: I agree with LVW when he says that the phase margin, when related to system stability, should be calculated or measured taking into account the open loop path. That value of 82.6 degrees is meaningless unless the filter transfer function was part of other feedback loop. There is no such thing as "closed loop phase margin". The gain and phase margins are calculated based only on the open loop system response.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should increase the number of points to be calculated (better resolution).

However, a short look on your simulation results reveals that the circuit most probably is unstable. For a stable system the phase response must always have a negative slope. However, in your case - in the center frequency region - the slope is positive. This is an indication for instability. However, perhaps the situation changes with a new simulation with better resolution (I cannot see WHY the circuit should be unstable)

For a detailed stability check you need to analyze the loop gain. Application of the Nyquist stability criterion is beased on the loop gain response only.
For this purpose, open the C2 path and inject an ac test signal Vin. The ratio Vout/Vin gives the loop gain.
(Please note, that the Barkhausen criterion is an oscillation condition and NOT a stability criterion).

Comment: Is there a reference for the negative slope thing??

Comment: At center frequency fo an inverting bandpass must have a phase shift of -180deg. Below fo the phase is -90deg Hence, we have a falling characteristic, which must continue to -270 deg for frequencies above fo. More than that, the group delay [-d(phi)/dw] must be positive.

Comment: I think you're looking a a tangent unwrapping artifact.

Comment: @Scott Seidman: It is a well-known fact that each allpol-filter exhibits a FALLING phase characteristic. More than that, if a circuit with feedback is unstable, the magnitude characteristic of an ac analysis cannot reveal this property. You have to look at the phase - and if the phase exhibits a rising character this is a clear indication of instability. Since this is the case with the shown BODE plot, I have asked the questioner to perform a more careful analysis.

Comment: @LvW, Can you explain lead compensation in this context? (I suspect I'm confusing what I know about loop transfer functions with closed-loop transfer functions, but humor me)

Comment: For all the phase points in the original post that are greater than -50 deg, subtract 360, and you get Andy's phase plot.  If you add 360 to that result, you'll get mine.  The phase does not show a rising character.  You're looking at a tangent unwrapping problem.  The data generated from the original simulation match the calculations from the ideal transfer function, which have been shown stable from the pole calculations and from the phase margin.

Comment: I did nothing else than to comment the original phase plot which looks to me rather uncommon. I know how the phase of an inverting bandpass looks like. The core of my recommendation to the questioner was to improve his simulation (better resolution).

Comment: @The photon: My comment regarding a falling phase characteristic was related to ALLPOL filters - not to lead-compensated networks.

Comment: @LvW, "ALLPOL" is not a term used commonly in EE in the US. Could you explain what it means? (I assume a pole with poles only, but why not just say that if that's what you meant?) Also your answer says, "For a stable system the phase response must always have a negative slope." with no restriction on circuit topology.

Comment: @The Photon: Sorry for using a term not known to you. For my opinion, it is a common term in filter theory. Allpol filters are all filter functions without real zero´s. For example, Cauer and Chebyshev-invers filter functions do NOT belong to this class.

Comment: @LvW Google doesn't reveal (on the first page) any use of this term ("allpol filter") that aren't written in German. Similarly, in google books, all relevant usage of the term (on the first page of search results) seem to be in German-language texts.

Comment: "For a detailed stability check you need to analyze the loop gain. " Could you please further illustrate on this? I agree on this very much, however do not know how.. Is there any doc on this?

Comment: @LvW And since Barkhausen criterion does not garantee stability, what else could be checked?

Comment: @The photon: Yes - you are right. I admit that this term (allpole filter) is not as common as I thought. However, it can be found on Wikipedia ("Other all-pole second-order filters may roll off at different rates initially depending on their Q factor, but approach the same final rate of 12 dB per octave"). Thank you.

Comment: @Richieqianle: The most popular stability criterion (Nyquist criterion, Nyquist plot) is based on loop gain evaluation. A detailed description and justification can be found in each textbook dealing with feedback systems. The Barkhausen criterion is nothing else than a NECESSARY condition (NOT sufficient) for a feedback circuit to oscillate. Note that "instability" not necessarily means "oscillation"; very often it is just saturation at supply voltage level.

Comment: @LvW： I use the Middlebrook method(http://www.designers-guide.org/Forum/Attachments/Loop_gain.pdf) to find the loop gain and its phase. And found that the phase margin is about 68 degree when the gain is 0dB. Do you think the phase margin is enough?(as I learned that larger than 45 degree is OK)

Comment: @LvW Thanks for your reply! Could I ask if Nyquist Criterion is the same with comparing transfer functions of the active filter?

Comment: @billyzhao: Middlebrook method is fine (most accurate). Of course, a PM=68 deg. is sufficient.

Comment: @richieqianle: Sorry, but I don´t understand the contents and the meaning of your question (...comparing with what?).

Comment: @LvW I mean comparing with checking the transfer function of active filters, to see if they only have negative real part poles.

Comment: @richieqianle: Yes - if all poles of the closed-loop function have negative real parts only the circuit is stable. However, very often one wishes to know HOW stable it is - that means: How much margin exists until it becomes unstable. And for this purpose we need satbility criteria which are based on the LOOP GAIN only (Nyquist plot or BODE diagrams).